# JPA onetomany on same entity

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I am trying to create a entity as follows

```
 @Data
    public class Person
    {
    @Id
    private String id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="id")
 private List<person> friends;
    }
```

Letting JPA create entity and i am able to persist person with friends as null

when trying to save a new person with friends list populated , the relation is not visible in RDBMS and its not throwing any error while saving.

Not able to figure out is the friend data actually getting stored ? If yes , how to access it ?

Comment: mappedBy is supposed to point to a field in the other type of type Person. It doesn't. Suggest you go and read some JPA documentation

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :-) Given your deep "expertise" in JPA could you please let me know how to have the above relation mapped ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: You were advised to look at JPA documentation. Any JPA documentation would tell you how to map a 1-N bidirectional relation. Such as http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/orm/one_to_many_collection.html#fk_bi   Why is that so hard to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have two tables, `Person` and `Person_Friends`. The `Person` class looks as below:

**NOTE**: To keep it simple, I have used `IDENTITY` as `GenerationType` and `int` as datatype for `id`.

```
@Entity
class Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="Person_Friends")
    List<Person> friends = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", friends=" + friends + "]";
    }
}
```

The code to save a sample `Person` object with `friends`:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
Person p = new Person();
p.friends.add(new Person());
p.friends.add(new Person());
p.friends.add(new Person());
p.friends.add(new Person());
entityManager.persist(p);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

> Not able to figure out is the friend data actually getting stored ?

With this schema you should be able to find friends data in `Person_Friends` table.

> If yes , how to access it ?

Loading the `Person` object for whom you want to view the friends data should populate the `friends` list as well although lazily for this mapping.

In case you want to see the auto-generated tables used here, the DDLs below:

```
    create table Person (
        id integer generated by default as identity,
        primary key (id)
    )

    create table Person_Friends (
        Person_id integer not null,
        friends_id integer not null
    )

    alter table Person_Friends 
        add constraint UK_4ehyhs34ebu5gl6k8u5ckd2u7 unique (friends_id)

    alter table Person_Friends 
        add constraint FKjvrny03ut8h70garyw5ehnlr7 
        foreign key (friends_id) 
        references Person

    alter table Person_Friends 
        add constraint FK85ngln3801hk33fkhhsl7b8e7 
        foreign key (Person_id) 
        references Person
```

Comment: That code seems to be Hibernate API not JPA API, yet the question does state JPA API. Perhaps you ought to change it to reflect the question?

Comment: @BillyFrost That is good catch as the question title is indicating the OP is interested in JPA. Updated the answer.